# how to add cm^2 as proper legend in ggplot in R

Tags: r

I want to use "cm^2" as my y-axis. How to get a proper squared on the right upper side of cm? I'm using `ggplot` in R.
My function looks like

```
ggplot(dataset,aes(x=as.numeric('xxx'), y=as.numeric('yyy') + geom_point(alpha=0.85,size=1.85) + 
labs(x="Mean recovery",col="area (cm^2)") + 
labs(y="yyy (xx/cm2)", size=2))
```

I'm wondering how to change cm^2 as cm with 2 at the upper right side of cm?
[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with some sample data

Comment: I just want to change the label of the legend